# Explanation of lastIndex of: and firstIndex of: used in a string in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, lastindexof

I am solving a programming problem in Swift and I found a solution online which I don't totally understand, the problem is: Write a function that reverses characters in (possibly nested) parentheses in the input string. the solution is

```
var inputString = "foo(bar)baz(ga)kjh"

    var s = inputString
    while let openIdx = s.lastIndex(of: "(") {
        let closeIdx = s[openIdx...].firstIndex(of:")")!
        s.replaceSubrange(openIdx...closeIdx, with: s[s.index(after: openIdx)..<closeIdx].reversed())
    }

print (s) // output: foorabbazagkjh (the letters inside the braces are reversed)
```

I d like to have details about: `lastIndex(of:` does in this case
and what `let closeIdx = s[openIdx...].firstIndex(of:")")!` does as well

Comment: The documentation would be a good start: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997132-lastindex, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997120-firstindex

Comment: Not related to your question but this would crash if it finds an opening bracket unbalanced. Don't force unwrap it `let closeIdx = s[openIdx...].firstIndex(of:")")!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to experiment with these kinds of questions would [Playground](https://www.apple.com/sg/swift/playgrounds/). Also, check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string).

Now let go through each of the statement:

```
let openIdx = s.lastIndex(of: "(") // it will find the last index of "(", the return type here is Array.Index?
```

so if I print the value after with index including till end of string, it would be

```
print(s[openIdx!...]) // `!` exclamation is used for forced casting
// (ga)kjh
```

Now for your second question;

```
let closeIdx = s[openIdx...].firstIndex(of:")")!
```

Let break it down `s[openIdx...]` is equal to `(ga)kjh` in first iteration and so it will return the index of `)` after `a`.

The suggestion would be always break the statement and learn what each expression is doing.